# Is it possible to import a formula from another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, import

I have a master spreadsheet, call it Master, and a lot of copies of this spreadsheet, one for every person in my organization, because they need their own copy. The Master sheet has a lot of formulas.

Is it possible to update a formula in the Master, and reflect the update on all the "sons" spreadsheets without editing everyone (like ImportRange but with formulas and not values)?

PS: Is the same possible also for the script sheet?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in function similar to IMPORTRANGE that import formulas.

It's possible to do this with Google Apps Script. Use the getFormula / setFormula for single formulas and getFormulas / setFormulas for formulas in a range.